# How to make a function which normally returns a value, return undefined rather than null when the value cannot be found

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I wrote a simple function to get a value from a referrer:

```
 export const getParamFromReferrer = ({ param }) =>
   !!document.referrer &&
   new URLSearchParams(new URL(document.referrer).search).get(param);
```

When no value is found, the function returns `null`. How can I ensure it always returns `undefined` instead?

Comment: At the moment this can return `false` as well as `null`. `false` when `document.referrer` is an empty string and `null` when `.get()` can't find the param. Do you want to leave the `false` behavior as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the *return* statement to use [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that checks whether the value is null and returns `undefined`:

```
export const getParamFromReferrer = ({ param }) =>
  !!document.referrer
    ? new URLSearchParams(new URL(document.referrer).search).get(param) || undefined
    : undefined;
```

The above code returns `undefined` by default if the parameter is not found, and it uses the `||` operator to return `undefined` if the parameter value is *falsy*.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! It's a very simple solution but I just couldn't get my head round it